# How do I get the username of the logged-in user?

Tags: users

I am working on a site where on a page I am querying some data related to my project.

Here I have many clients and I have given all of them access to project search page. On search page I run a query according to the fields selected by the user and display the result as a table on the page itself. But my query is as such that it is not user dependent.

I just want to ensure that each user has a specific set of output for itself (i.e not all the table would be displayed to all users).

How do I get the username or user ID of the logged-in user?

Comment: You have access to the current user with the global variable `global $user`. So you can have `$userlogin = $user->login;`, `$userID = $user->uid;`, etc ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [global `$user` object](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/user/7):

> An object representing the user currently visiting the site.
>
> Contains preferences and other account information for logged-in users. When a user is not logged-in, the $user->uid property is set to 0.

e.g.

```
global $user;
$name = $user->name;
$id = $user->uid;

// or
$name = $GLOBALS['user']->name;
$id = $GLOBALS['user']->uid;
```

Comment: Where should I write this piece of code in my website.

Comment: Wherever you need to use it....

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
   global $user;      
   if (!empty($user->uid))
   {$id = $user->uid;} //$id will only have a value if user is logged in
```

Comment: _When a user is not logged-in, the $user->uid property is set to 0._ ...if you're looking to test whether or not the user is actually logged in `user_is_logged_in()` and `user_is_anonymous()` would probably be more appropriate

Comment: 0 will return empty() to be TRUE so $id will not be set!

Comment: Yeah sorry, hadn't finished writing that comment when I submitted it :)